# Почему эта функция работает медленней чем его однопроцессный вариант

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, signal

Есть функция проверки числа на простоту в однопроцессном режиме и есть в много процессном.Я не могу понять почему функция для многопроцессного режима работает медленней ее однопроцессного варианта. В чем моя ошибка?

```
bool Prime::is_prime(numeric_t num)  {
    if ((std::abs(num) != 2 && num % 2 == 0) || std::abs(num) == 1 || num == 0)
        return false;
    NumericRange range(2, static_cast<numeric_t> (std::sqrt(std::abs(num)) + 1));
    for (auto it = range.begin(); it < range.end(); ++it)
        if (num % (*it) == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

static void wait_all(std::vector<pid_t> childs) {
for (pid_t pid: childs)
    while (waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0) > 0);
}

static void term_all(std::vector<pid_t> childs) {
    for (pid_t pid: childs)
        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
}

namespace {
    sig_atomic_t prime = true;
}

void handler(int sig) {
    sigset_t set;
    if (sigemptyset(&set))                      return;
    if (sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1))               return;
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, nullptr))  return;

    prime = false;

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, nullptr)) return;
}

bool ParallelPrime::is_prime(numeric_t num, long nproc) {
    if (nproc <= 0 || nproc == 1 || num < 999999)
        return Prime::is_prime(num);

    if (num % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    NumericRange range(3, static_cast<numeric_t>(std::sqrt(num)) + 1);
    if (std::distance(range.begin(), range.end()) < nproc)
        return Prime::is_prime(num);

    auto block_size = std::distance(range.begin(), range.end()) / nproc;
    std::vector<pid_t> childs(nproc - 1);

    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
    auto block_start = range.begin();

    for (auto & child: childs) {
        auto block_end = block_start;
        std::advance(block_end, block_size);

        child = fork();
        if (child < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Can't create process." << std::endl;
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (child > 0) {
            block_start = block_end;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            for (auto it = block_start; it != block_end; ++it)
                if (num % (*it) == 0) {
                    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                    std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    if (!prime) {
        term_all(childs);
        return false;
    }
    wait_all(childs);
    for (auto it = block_start; it != range.end(); ++it)
        if (num % (*it) == 0)
            return false;
    return prime != 0;
}
```

Comment: я не совсем понял, вас интересует почему `Prime::is_prime` медленнее `ParallelPrime::is_prime`?

Comment: Нет, совсем наоборот: меня интересует почему ParallelPrime::is_prime работает медленнее Prime::is_prime. Для проверки я использовал это число '92233720368547757'. Проверял утилитой time

Comment: Не знаю, что это за утилита, но лучше используйте `gprof` - на его результаты точно можно положится, заодно кроме времени, выдаст и количество вызовов - вот тогда и можно будет судить о том что не так.

Comment: также не совсем понятен принцип вашей рекурсии - в первом вызове функции вы разбиваете задачу на ряд подзадач и в цикле создаете паралельные процессы, которые и выполняют задачу, вызывая, в свою очередь `Prime::is_prime`. Не думаю что такой подход хорош: если `Prime::is_prime` работает достаточно быстро, то пока вы в цикле создаете процессы они будут завершаться пока вы создаете следующий процесс. К тому же учтите, что создаваемые процессы не обязательно будут паралельно выполняться (в случае, например, если недостаточно вычислительных возможностей).

Comment: Не вижу из примеров чему равен nproc при вызове. И еще не понимаю строку `if (std::distance(range.begin(), range.end()) < nproc)
        return Prime::is_prime(num);`

Comment: Нет, рекурсии как раз таки и нет. А что на счет std::distance(), то если размер интервала меньше чем количество процессов, то лучше выполнить задачу в однопроцессном режиме в точности вызвав Prime::is_prime(). Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, о каком времени выполнения и о какой разнице этого времени вообще речь ?

Comment: Mike, я использовал утилиту time и она выдает реальное время выполнения функции для параллельной проверки числа на простоту больше чем в однопроцессном режиме. Возможно так медленно потому что время уходит на создание и ожидание закрытия процесса. Потому предоставил код, чтоб указали при возможности недостатки. Спасибо.

Comment: Просто приведите числа, в однопроцессрном столько то минут, в многопроцессорном столько то. Время запуска пустого процесса такое то. количество процессов такое то и количество ядер такое то

Comment: Для проверки использую число '121220999999'                                                                    
В однопроцессном режиме: real - 0m0,004s; user - 0m0,000s; sys - 0m0,003s.                   В многопроцессном режиме(4 процесса, по числу ядер) real - 0m0,008s; user - 0m0,008s; sys - 0m0,000s.

Comment: вот этого я и опасался ... время старта дочернего процесса очень велико, на таких малых величинах времени невозможно ни о чем сказать. дочерние процессы должны отработать хотя бы полсекунды, что бы оправдать свой запуск. Корректный тест надо сделать таким, что бы он работал несколько секунд

Comment: Mike, хорошо учту это) А по коду есть замечания?

Comment: Непонятна логика с term_all/wait_all. Почему после wait_all не проверяется флаг prime? Почему проверка в родительском процессе делается не параллельно с дочерними, а после wait_all? И где остальной код? Почему здесь приведен только огрызок?